# Mac AppleScript to bulk-close dead Terminal windows

Tags: macos, terminal, automation, applescript, workflow

During any given script writing/testing session (via Mac BBEdit), I might have BBEdit execute my test script dozens of times before it's completed ready for production. Once I'm done testing, I'm left with a stack of 'zombie' Terminal windows to close.

This 'clean-up' task shown below is an AppleScript widget called from the BBEdit's customizable 'Scripts' menu bar icon. It used to work on older Monterey and Ventura Macs (which I no longer have to compare to unfortunately). Now that Im on Sonoma it no longer works. Not sure if the OS version is the issue or not, but that's the main thing that has changed recently.

```
tell application "Terminal"
set DEAD_WINDOWS to (every window whose processes = {})
repeat with WINDOW_TO_CLOSE in DEAD_WINDOWS
close WINDOW_TO_CLOSE
end repeat
end tell
```

The error message:

**Terminal got an error: AppleEvent handler failed. number -10000**

I get the same error from BBEdit or running straight form Apple's Script Editor.app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be hidden Terminals which does not belong to your user, try this :

```
set DEAD_WINDOWS to every window whose (visible is true and processes = {})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not running Sonoma so maybe this is not the issue you're experiencing. Let me know.

Anyways, it's possible that there is at least one stray window that you cannot get the processes of. Therefore, when your script asks for every window's processes, it fails with the -10000 error.

I had three visible terminal windows open but when I ran this command, it indicated that there were five windows.

```
tell application "Terminal" to windows
--> {window id 35966 of application "Terminal", window id 28835 of application ¬
    "Terminal", window id 33742 of application "Terminal", window id 36166 ¬
    of application "Terminal"}
```

Since getting the processes all at once failed, I tried looping through the windows, like so.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    set wl to windows
    repeat with w in wl
        processes of w
    end repeat
end tell
```

Reviewing the log told me that the problem was specific to the last window. I could not get the processes for window id 36166 even when I focused on it. I then grabbed every window's name and noticed that it was an anomalous `"New Command"`

```
    get every window
        --> {window id 35966, window id 28835, window id 33742, window id 36166}
    get processes of window id 35966
        --> {"login", "-zsh"}
    get processes of window id 28835
        --> {"login", "-zsh"}
    get processes of window id 33742
        --> {"login", "-zsh", "man", "sh", "sh", "sh", "less"}
    get processes of window id 36166
        --> error number -10000

    tell application "Terminal" to get processes of window id 36166
    --> error "Terminal got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." number -10000

    name of windows
        --> {"Terminal — zsh — 116×51", "Terminal — zsh — 133×30", ¬
    "Terminal — zsh — 120×24", "New Command"}
```

So, I filtered out any such windows and then looped through the remainder and closed them.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    set wList to windows whose name is not "New Command"
    
    repeat with w in wList
        if processes of w is {} then close w
    end repeat
end tell
```

FWIW, if you're going to use a loop as you do, there isn't really an advantage to the filtering command being outside the loop. This case is an exception in that you need to filter out those windows that choke the script.